# Increment a value in of an atom

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am learning clojurescript and i came across this snippet.

```
:on-click (fn [] (swap! state/order update (:id gig) inc))
```

I looked up the docs for `update` function and it said that update takes in a key and a functions. Passes the old value from the atom to the function and then update the atom. If there is no existing value for the key in atom nil is passed as input to the function.
When i tried the same thing in the repl it did not work

```
(def atom-test (atom {}))
(swap! atom-test update :aa inc)
NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Numbers.ops (Numbers.java:1013)
```

Adding `fnil` to catch this NullPointerException worked.

```
user=> (swap! atom-test update :aa (fnil inc 0))
{:aa 1}
```

I cannot understand why it works in case 1 in clojurescript and why it does not work in case 2 in clojure repl. Can anyone explain whats the trick here.

Comment: The same reason, you can enter `1 + null` in your browser console to get `1` without an error.  I'd use `fnil` on both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cljs, it is common for operations to safely handle nil without causing exceptions.

```
cljs.user=> (update {} :a inc)
{:a 1}
cljs.user=> (inc nil)
1
cljs.user=> (+ 1 nil)
1
```

https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/nil

Comment: I thought Clojure and ClojureScript function similarly.

Answer (score 2):

The `inc` function requires an argument that satisfies `number?`. This is true in Clojure and ClojureScript.

If you pass something else, like `nil`, the program is incorrect: `(inc nil)` has undefined behavior. This is not safe to do. It just so happens to return `1` but that is not guaranteed and is an accident of implementation.

If, for example, you instead pass a literal string to `inc`, ClojureScript will emit a warning at compile time:

```
cljs.user=> (inc "a")
WARNING: cljs.core/+, all arguments must be numbers, got [string number] instead at line 1 <cljs repl>
```

Perhaps in the future, the compiler could similarly emit a warning for `(inc nil)`, but what is more likely to happen is that specs will be written covering core functions, with `cljs.core/inc` being specified to accept an argument satisfying `number?`.

TL;DR: using `fnil` is the correct thing to do here.